# Next.js 13.4.3: Website not updating after adding new posts on hosting, despite successful GET request to API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, frontend

I am using next js 13.4.3 from app directory. I'm making a blog site, but I have a little problem. When I type `npm run build` locally on my computer and then `npm run start`, then after adding a new post to my headles cms(hygraph) and sending a GET request to my api, the page updates normally, new posts are shown. The problem starts when I upload my website to hosting, after adding a new post and sending a GET request to the api, the website does not update. I am sending the code below:

**page.tsx:**

```
import BlogCard from '@/components/blog/PostCard';
import styles from './blog.module.scss';

const hygraphContentApi = "URI HERE";

interface Post {
  title: string;
  createdAt: string;
  slug: string;
  shortDescription: string;
  author: {
    name: string;
    picture: {
      url: string;
    };
  };
  coverImage: {
    url: string;
  };
}

const QUERY = `
query {
  posts {
    title
    createdAt
    shortDescription
    slug
    author {
      name
      picture {
        url
      }
    }
    coverImage {
      url
    }
  }
}
`

export default async function Home() {
  const response: { data: { posts: Post[]}} = await fetch(hygraphContentApi, {
    
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: QUERY,
    })
  }).then(res => res.json())
  const posts = [...response.data.posts].sort((a, b) => {
    const dateA: Date = new Date(a.createdAt);
    const dateB: Date = new Date(b.createdAt);
    return dateB.getTime() - dateA.getTime();
  });
  return (
    <main>
      {posts ? (
        <div className={styles.blogCardsContainer}>
        {posts.length > 0 ? (
          posts.map((post) => (
            <BlogCard key={post.slug} post={JSON.stringify(post)} />
          ))
        ) : (
          null 
        )}
        </div>  
      ) : <div className={styles.loading}>Loading...</div>}
    </main>
  );
};
```

**route.tsx (api):**

```
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  const url = new URL(req.url);
  const auth = url.searchParams.get('auth');
  const path = url.searchParams.get('path')
  if(!path) return NextResponse.json({revalidated: false}, {status: 400})
  if(!auth) return NextResponse.json({revalidated: false}, {status: 400})
  if(auth != process.env.HYGRAPH_WEBHOOK_REVALIDATE_AUTHID) return NextResponse.json({revalidated: false}, {status: 401})
  revalidatePath(path)
  return NextResponse.json({revalidated: true, message: 'OK'}, {status: 200})
}
```

After sending a get request on the hosting, I get a message that everything was successful.
I tried clearing the cache on the hosting, and re-deploying, but it didn't help...

Comment: You should probably be revalidating the path on your POST request. And also the path you need to revalidate is the UI path, not the endpoint path (that confused me at first).  You also need to call router.refresh() in some instances. I found this video super helpful on understanding what's going on with server mutations https://youtu.be/BmUsDuLO598.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I changed from GET to POST and [this is what my code looks like](https://gist.github.com/KubaZary1/1b5188f8b90808cbff91137fe68fb4a5).
Can you explain to me now the difference between *ui path* and *endpoint path*?

Answer (score -1):

First i recommend that you create posts state with the hook `useState`, this will be importante to the next steps:

```
const [post, setPosts] = useState();
```

Then you need to create a function with the request to API, it is not necessary but i recommend you tu use `useCallback` to create this function, this will save memory of your application:

```
const getPosts = useCallback(async () => {
  const response: { data: { posts: Post[]}} = await fetch(hygraphContentApi, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: QUERY,
    })
  }).then(res => res.json())
  const data = [...response.data.posts].sort((a, b) => {
    const dateA: Date = new Date(a.createdAt);
    const dateB: Date = new Date(b.createdAt);
    return dateB.getTime() - dateA.getTime();
  });
  setPosts(data || [])
}, [])
```

Then you need to call this function with `useEffect` in first render of your page:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getPosts();
  // If you leave the dependencies empty this will be called only once;
}, [])
```

This code should make the request when user render your page and also render your posts.

## Edit

If you want server side rendering you can use `getStaticProps`, here is the docs:
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-static-props

In this situation instead of react hooks you will make the request in `getStaticProps` and this is the function that you will fetch all data that you to be pre-loaded.

Here is an example:

```
export const geetStaticProps = async () => {
  const response: { data: { posts: Post[]}} = await fetch(hygraphContentApi, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: QUERY,
    })
  }).then(res => res.json())
  const posts = [...response.data.posts].sort((a, b) => {
    const dateA: Date = new Date(a.createdAt);
    const dateB: Date = new Date(b.createdAt);
    return dateB.getTime() - dateA.getTime();
  });
  
  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
    // If you want to refetch automatically
    revalidate: 10, // In seconds
  }
}
```

and then you can get this data as props in your page component:

```
export async function Home({ posts }) {
  // ...
  // Here you can use posts as a variable
}
```

Comment: It works, but the problem is that each time the page is accessed, a request is sent to hygraph, I want the page to save posts (so it doesn't have to send a request to hygraph every time), and refresh the list when I send a POST request to my api

Comment: You need to change your dropdown in the Next docs to the app router to see the docs related to the OP's question.

Comment: unfortunately getStaticProps doesn't work in app directory